# Redirecting the user to the admin table area after publishing a post, getting an invalid response error?

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor, wp-redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user back to the custom post type page in the admin area after they publish a post but i'm always getting the error:

`Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.`

Here's what my code looks like for redirecting:

```
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'redirect_after_save_post'); 

function get_redirect_url(){
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])){
        $page = $_GET['post_type'];
        return admin_url('edit.php?post_type=' . $page);
    }
}

function redirect_after_save_post($post_id){
    wp_redirect(get_redirect_url());
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `wp_after_insert_post` hook to run the redirect.. "*after they publish a post*" - you mean, via the block/Gutenberg editor, or is it the classic editor?

Comment: @SallyCJ It is via the gutenberg editor. Anyway, i figured out the problem and its because save_post or wp_after_insert_post runs before post metas are done saving/updating. I did the redirection in js instead and using this https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and you should post an answer and include your code.

Comment: So what is the solution here? @Duts ?

Comment: @File_Submit By checking if the post is done successfully saving and then simply using window.location.replace to mimic  a redirect. I recommend checking this out https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/. I've particularly used isSavingPost and didPostSaveRequestSucceed selectors to determine if the post is done saving.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working approach with jQuery. Using **setTimeout** twice because of timing issue. The first **setTimeout** is used to load the code after everything is loaded on the page.

The second **setTimeout** is needed to delay page redirection, so Ajax can actually update/publish the post and for better user experience.

```
    // Redirect to All posts dashboard after post update/publish
function webroomtech_redirect_to_post_list() {
?>
<script>
// On "publish / update / submit changes" button click, redirect to cpt listing
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Getting the post type to work for post, pages, custom post types etc.
    let postType = document.querySelector('form.metabox-base-form input#post_type').value;

    var url = '/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=' + postType;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.editor-post-publish-button__button').on('click', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);

        });
    }, 5000);
  
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'webroomtech_redirect_to_post_list' );
```

I've published the answer originally here: https://www.webroomtech.com/redirect-to-all-posts-after-post-update-or-publish-in-block-editor/

Comment: Glad that works, but relying on timings always feels risky to me. There aren't events you can hook instead?

Comment: @Rup see my comment in my post. I explained how I did mine without relying on setTimeOuts which I think is a really bad solution.